# How can I calculate the following double limit? Or does it diverge?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x, y)\to(0,2)}\left(\frac{y\sin(xe^y)}{x}\right)$$

Here we deal with $\frac{0}{0}$ indeterminate form. What I could see is that
$$\left|\frac{y\sin(xe^y)}{x} \right| \leq \left|\frac{y}{x}\right|$$

but what to do with that I don't know. If the $y \to 0$ I would know that it diverges.

Comment: Hint: try to multiply and divide the expression by $e^y$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\lim_{(x, y)\to(0,2)}\left(\frac{y\sin(xe^y)}{x}\right)=
\lim_{(x, y)\to(0,2)}\left(\frac{y\sin(xe^y)}{xe^y}e^y\right)
=\lim_{(x, y)\to(0,2)}ye^y\cdot\left(\frac{\sin(xe^y)}{xe^y}\right).
$$
Now it should be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that$$\frac{y\sin(xe^y)}x=ye^y\frac{\sin(xe^y)}{xe^y},$$together with $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin z}z=1$. It follows from these remarks that your limit is equal to $2e^2$.